# How to put element inside closed tag

Tags: html

I'm still a novice at webdev and this is my first question here so please bare with me. I'm currently working on a website for my school and I'm trying to add a search box like this(with the search icon inside the box): [click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vwWn.png)

I'm following the search bar tutorial from w3schools, but their version is a bit different(search icon on the outside): [click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fzLi.png)

This is the html code for the search bar:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
```

I want to put the search icon inside the box like the first picture, but the input tag is a empty tag, so I don't know how to put it inside. Please help me.

Comment: You might want to learn how css work.
And also check out how others are doing via css https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-to-put-icon-inside-an-input-element-in-a-form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used font awesome for search icon, u can use local search icon, font awesome icons, material design icons or any icon source just use this below code.

```css
.custom-select {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    outline: none;
    height: 50px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 555;
}

.custom-select-search-icon {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.custom-select-input {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: transparent;
    color: #051833;
}
```

```html
<!-- Load icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="custom-select">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search please" class="custom-select-input">

     <i class="fa fa-search custom-select-search-icon"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a basic idea of how it can be done:

```js
document.getElementById('sb').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName =='SPAN') {
        let elem = e.target.children[0];
        elem.focus();
    }
});
```

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.outer img {
   height: 22px;
   width: 22px;
   top:5px;
   position:relative;
}

input {
  /* Tell the input to use all the available space */
  flex-grow:2;
  /* And hide the input's outline, so the form looks like the outline */
  border:none;
}

input:focus {
  /* removing the input focus blue box. Put this on the form if you like. */
  outline: none;
}

button {
  /* Just a little styling to make it pretty */
  border:1px solid blue;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<span class="outer" id="sb">
   <input placeholder="Search.."/>
   <img src="http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/585e4ad1cb11b227491c3391.png">
</span>
```